# Why doesn't GCC generate a warning for loss of resolution?

Tags: gcc

Consider the following code fragment:

```
long long someVar64 = 0LL;
int someVar32 = someVar64;
```

In case it's not obvious, there's a potential bug here in that the 64-bit value is being assigned to a 32-bit value, resulting in loss of bits. In this case it's fine because we don't care about the upper bits for 0 but if I change the constant I could easily create a bug.

Why doesn't GCC (4.4.3) generate a warning for this code? I recall that older versions used to.

Comment: Did you try explicitly enabling this warning `-Wconversion`?

Comment: You don't specify what flags you're using to invoke GCC, but at the very least you should be using `-Wall` as a starting point.

Answer (score 3):

This warning is enabled by -Wconversion. Note that it is not enabled by -Wall or -Wextra.

> -Wconversion
>
> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. This includes conversions 
>   between real and integer, like `abs (x)` when x is
>   double; conversions between signed and unsigned, like 
>   `unsigned ui = -1;` and conversions to smaller types, like `sqrtf (M_PI).`
>
> Do not warn for explicit casts like `abs ((int) x)` and `ui = (unsigned) -1`, 
>   or if the value is not changed by the conversion like in `abs (2.0)`.
>
> [...]

Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options